# Question about hard well potential in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, reflection, scattering

How we can treat the potential that is infinity on one side and zero for other side
$$V(x)=\begin{cases}0~~~~~~~~~x>0\\ +\infty~~~~~ x<0 \end{cases}$$
I think we must apply the one boundary condition we have
$ψ(0)=0$. Then $ψ(x)=A\sin (kx)$ and the energies be allowed for any value bigger than the minimum potential value will be
$$E=\frac{ħ^2k^2}{2m}$$
can be any real positive value.
Is that true?

Comment: The boundary conditions are that wavefunction vanishes where the potential infinite. So you have only to solve the equation in the region where it is finite.

Comment: In this sort of exercise, energy is typically quantized when the particle is in a bound state. Your potential isn't a well, so the particle doesn't have to be in a bound state, so energy doesn't have to be quantized.

Comment: Yeah , That's right but the application of one boundary condition and hence we get the sine wave function is true?